# Can set up jenkins server with Opsworks

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins server through AWS Opsworks. I added the https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins to the custom recipes section. And added the jenkins::master to the set up step in the event life cycle. However, when ever I try to create an instance I get the following errors:

```
[2015-11-07T21:12:41+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-11-07T21:12:41+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-11-07T21:12:41+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to     /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-11-07T21:12:41+00:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"
[2015-11-07T21:12:41+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I also see this error higher up in the log file:

```
Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: apt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi -- I'm not that familiar with Opsworks, but you're missing cookbooks that are dependencies of the Jenkins cookbook (specifically the apt cookbook, but I'm sure there are others). Did you actually upload the jenkins cookbook _and all dependencies_ to Opsworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) to manage cookbook dependencies, there is no need to store community cookbooks within your own repository.

in short: specify cookbooks dependencies and their constraint (if any) within a `Berksfile`, something like:

```
# Berksfile
source 'https://supermarket.getchef.com'
cookbook 'apt', '2.0.0'
```

then execute `berks install && berks vendor --path vendor/cookbooks`. make sure to upload all cookbooks to your chef server (or manage correctly any other entity, e.g. [test-kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen)) by executing `knife cookbook upload --all --cookbook-path vendor/cookbooks` or `knife cookbooks upload --all --include-dependencies`.

if you configured everything correctly, then you should have no problem.
make sure to store `Berksfile.lock` within your repository.

Comment: @Could someone clarify the problem? I am facing exact the same problem but I totally newbie on chef.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the metadata.rb file on the [git](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins) repo:
it clearly indicates these are dependencies which are probably missing on your OpsWorks repo:

- depends 'apt',   ' 2.0'
- depends 'runit', ' 1.5'
- depends 'yum',   ' 3.0'

You need to add those cookbooks (in those versions) to your opsworks git repo.
You may need to run OpsWorks task of updating custom cookbooks after so it will take effect, here's [how](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-installingcustom-enable-update.html).